# providing locks on shared resources

Tags: multithreading, locking

So i'm trying to get my head around threads using shared resources.
The examples on c#corner (link 1) and msdn (link 2) provide basic syntax examples and some theoretical framing, so the basic premise of locking a shared resource for a process I understand. Now, my question is:

When accessing and manipulating multiple shared resources in the same code block (in the "pseudocode" below a looping crawler process that pops a URL from a shared stack, evaluates the current url to a shared list of already checked URL's, and then pushes the downloaded data to another shared stack), do I need to enclose each segment of code that pertains to a specific shared resource within an lock statement?

It would seem so as the "lock (this) {}" structure in c# implements "Monitor" (link 3) in the background, and Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit both only take a single object as parameter.

In honesty, I haven't coded this out and tested it yet. but I was wondering about this as I was reading and afterward when I was laying out the structure of the code (the "pseudocode" below). I capitalized the begin and end points of the lock structure where I suspect them to be if my assumption is correct.

Anyone who can clarify/validate this for me?

(As i haven't acquired the necessary reputation score i posted the links like this, you can find them at the bottom;  @mods: if i violated anything doing this, let me know and I'll modify the post.)

```
program starts;

stack (urlsToCheck) is created (static, String);
list (checkedUrls) is created (static, String);
stack (unparsedHTML) is created (static, Tuple(string, Byte[]);

user provides seed url;
seed url is pushed to top op stack (urlsTocheck);
thread is created for Crawler method GetData();
<!--research possibilities for multiple threads in relation to stack sizes-->
<!--in case of multiple threads : threadpool + object (crawler) array?-->
thread is started:
Crawler 1 is created;
Crawler 1 starts method GetData:
loop:
<!--//check loop for lock/unlock locations//-->
    Crawler 1 evaluates size of stack (unparsedHTML):
        if(size > 100):
            wait 1000 ms;
            Crawler 1 evaluates size of stack (unparsedHTML);
        else:
            continue;
    LOCK;
    Crawler 1 evaluates size of stack (urlsToCheck):
        if(size > 0):
            Crawler 1 pops url from stack (urlsToCheck);
            continue;
        else:
            wait 1000 ms;
            Crawler 1 evaluates size of stack (urlsToCheck);
    Crawler 1 evaluates url for membership in List (checkedUrls):
        if(membership):
            discard url;
            pop url from stack (urlsToCheck);
            evaluate url for membership in List (checkedUrls);
        else:
            continue;
    UNLOCK;
    LOCK;
    Crawler 1 downloads data from url;
    Crawler makes tuple of url and data;
    Crawler pushes tuple onto stack (unparsedHTML);
    UNLOCK;
end loop;
```

1) http:// www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MultithreadingIntro10062005000439AM/MultithreadingIntro.aspx

2) https:// msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

3) https:// msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf5de04k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: just noticed i didn't delete my comments, you canignore those -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that, yes, you want to enclose each segment that pertains to a specific shared resource in a separate lock (similar to what you have above). A main reason is this helps minimize the amount of time any given thread is holding onto a resource. I have also found that it helps prevent the situation where a thread is holding a lock, but trying to obtain another lock which can quickly hang your program.  This is simply because your locking sections are usually shorter and it's easier to spot this problem in your code.  It's not fool-proof, but helps.

Obviously, there is cost involved in releasing and obtaining locks, so time or resource-sensitive environments need to find the right balance between the cost of frequently releasing and grabbing locks, versus the cost of waiting for locks.  In your example, that would mean does the program run faster if you hold just one lock around the whole block of code, or does it run faster if you stick to your current scheme of releasing and obtaining a new lock when moving to a new shared resource?  In my experience, the latter is better.

There are all sorts of caveats and exceptions to what I've said, and you may find some of your own when you actually implement the code, but your current thinking on how to do the locks is the way I would proceed.